# Android Remove <br/> in parsing rss

Tags: java, android, rss, toast

I am creating an app which pulls in an rss feed and displays the title and date. Once clicked, a Toast box will open and display the description for that rss feed story.

When you view the description in the toast view, it is pulling in the `< br/>` tags from the actual code on the RSS Feed. Can someone help me on how to remove the `< br/>` tags? I think I need them in the code still to keep the style of the story's text. But for the java to read it as HTML would so they wouldn't show in the toast view.

You can view the RSS feed [here](http://spaceflight1.nasa.gov/realdata/sightings/cities/rss/index.cgi?country=United_Kingdom&region=England&city=Manchester).

This is the code that shows the Toast but not sure if that will help.

```
   public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {


    Toast.makeText(this, episode_titles.get(position) + ": " + episode_description.get(position), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do something like this:

```
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
  String title = episode_titles.get(position);
  String descrip = episode_description.get(position);
  title = removeBr(title);
  descript = removeBr(descript);
  Toast.makeText(this, title + ": " +  descript, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

}


private String removeBr(String str1){
  return str1.replaceAll("<br/>", "");
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the code i can see where your coming from but i cant figure out how to make the function to work with removing the < br/> tags, is it possible for you to expand a bit more? I understand the function name should be removeBr then im guessing somethign like removeBr = (); with the script in the () to remove the tags. Thanks